# C++ program stops when entering input file

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, class, sorting

The following program basically asks for an input file then writes the results to an output file.  Its showing no errors in VisualStudio when I compile it.

When the program runs and asks for an input file, I type in the input file and hit enter the program just sits there with a flashing cursor. It doesn't go any further.  I can't figure out for the life of me whats going on.

Update: When using the debugger and stepping into "SalesRecord_Array read_records(ifstream& in, int &n)" I get the following errors in locals:

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYk14.png)

**Header file (sort.h):**

```
#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H
//A generic sorting function.

template<class T>
void sort(T a[], int number_used);
//Precondition: number_used <= declared size of the array a.
//The array elements a[0] through a[number_used - 1] have values.
//Postcondition: The values of a[0] through a[number_used - 1] have
//been rearranged so that a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[number_used - 1].

template<class T>
void swap_values(T& variable1, T& variable2);
//Interchanges the values of variable1 and variable2.

template<class T>
int index_of_smallest(const T a[], int start_index, int number_used);
//Precondition: 0 <= start_index < number_used. Array elements have values.
//Returns the index i such that a[i] is the smallest of the values
//a[start_index], a[star_index + 1], ..., a[number_used - 1].

template<class T>
void sort(T a[], int number_used)
{
    int index_of_next_smallest;
    for (int index = 0; index < number_used - 1; index++)
    {//Place the correct value in a[index]:
        index_of_next_smallest =
            index_of_smallest(a, index, number_used);
        swap_values(a[index], a[index_of_next_smallest]);
        //a[0] <= a[1] <=...<= a[index] are the smallest of the original array
        //elements. The rest of the elements are in the remaining positions.
    }
}

template<class T>
void swap_values(T& variable1, T& variable2)
{
    T temp;

    temp = variable1;
    variable1 = variable2;
    variable2 = temp;
}

template<class T>
int index_of_smallest(const T a[], int start_index, int number_used)
{
    T min = a[start_index];
    int index_of_min = start_index;

    for (int index = start_index + 1; index < number_used; index++)
        if (a[index] < min)
        {
            min = a[index];
            index_of_min = index;
            //min is the smallest of a[start_index] through a[index]
        }

    return index_of_min;
}
#endif
```

**Source file (source.cpp):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>        // For I/O   
#include <iomanip>        // For setw()
#include <cstdlib>         // For system()
#include <string>         // For stricmp()
#include "sort.h"           // Generic sort() function
using namespace std;

const int MAX_FILE_NAME = 35;  // Maximum file name length
const int MAX_ID_LEN = 10;  // Maximum length for items's id
const int MAX_NAME_LEN = 30;  // Maximum length for itemsloyee's name
const double DISCOUNT = 0.10;  // Quantity sold value at which commision rate changes
const double DISCOUNT_BREAK_POINT = 10;         // Regular commission per subscription sold 

class SalesRecord                      // Record definition for items's sales record
{
private:
    char   item_id[MAX_ID_LEN + 1];   // Items's id
    char   item_name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];// Items's name
    int    quantity_sold;            // Number of magazine subscriptions sold
    double regular_price;          // Commission on each subscription
    double discount_price;               // Salesperson's commission
    double total_price;  // Total price of items
public:
    // Functions that operate on an individual record
    void read(ifstream& in);         // Read record from input stream
    void calc_discount_price();          // Calculate commission fields in record
    void write(ostream & os) const;  // Write record to output stream
    int operator<(const SalesRecord& right) const;// Overloaded for use in sort
};

typedef SalesRecord * SalesRecord_Array; // Used to allocate 1-D sales record array

 // Utility functions - functions are not specific to this problem
void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]);           // Get file name & Open file
void open_output(ofstream& output, char name[]);         // Get file name & Open file

                                                         // Funcions that operate on array (set) of records
SalesRecord_Array read_records(ifstream& in, int &n);    // Allocate space for records & read them
void calc_discounts(SalesRecord_Array records, int n);     // Calculate commission rate and commission
void write_records(SalesRecord_Array records, int n);    // Save records to file

int  main()
// Parameters: None
// Returns:    Zero
// Calls:      open_input(), read_records(), calc_commissions(), sort(), write_records().
{
    char again;                                  // Does user want to go through loop again?
    int  num_records;                            // # of records 
    char infilename[MAX_FILE_NAME + 1];          // Name of file for records to be processed
    ifstream  in;                                // Input file stream
    SalesRecord_Array records = NULL;            // Pointer to array of sales records

    do
    {
        open_input(in, infilename);               // Get file name & open file
        records = read_records(in, num_records);  // Read records & get number of records
        in.close();                               // Close file
        if (num_records > 0)
        {
            calc_discounts(records, num_records);    // Calculate commission values for each record
            sort(records, num_records);            // Sort records by item name
            write_records(records, num_records);   // Save records to new file
            delete[] records;                     // Free array of records  
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\n\aNo data in file: " << infilename << endl;
        }

        cout << "\nDo you want to process another file (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');  // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
    } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');

    cout << "\n\n***** END OF PROGRAM ******\n";// Print closing message.    
    return 0;
}  // End of main()                

   // Utility functions
void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]) //Open file
// Parameters: Variables for input file reference nad input file name
// Returns:    None
// Calls:      None
{
    int count = 0;             // Count number of tries
    do // Continue until we get a valid file name and can open file
    {
        count++;
        if (count != 1)  // Issue error message if we are trying again.
        {
            cout << "\n\aInvalid file name or file does not exist. Please try again."
                << endl;
        }

        cout << "\nEnter the input file name (maximum of " << MAX_FILE_NAME
            << " characters please)\n:> ";
        cin.get(name, MAX_FILE_NAME + 1);// Gets at most MAX_FILE_NAME characters
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');           // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
        input.clear();                   // Clear all error flags, if any, from prev try
        input.open(name, ios_base::in); // Open only if file exists
    } while (input.fail());            // If can't open file, try again
} // End of open_input()

void open_output(ofstream& output, char name[]) //Open file
                                                // Parameters: Variables for output file reference and output file name
                                                // Returns:    None
                                                // Calls:      None
{
    int count = 0;             // Count number of tries
    do // Continue until we get a valid file name and can open file
    {
        count++;
        if (count != 1)  // Issue error message if we are trying again.
        {
            cout << "\n\aInvalid file name. Please try again."
                << endl;
        }

        cout << "\nEnter the output file name (maximum of " << MAX_FILE_NAME
            << " characters please)\n:> ";
        cin.get(name, MAX_FILE_NAME + 1);// Gets at most MAX_FILE_NAME characters
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');           // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
        output.clear();                  // Clear all error flags, if any, from prev try
        output.open(name);               // Open file for output
    } while (output.fail());           // If can't open file, try again
} // End of open_output()



void SalesRecord::read(ifstream& in)      // Read record from input stream, does not read commission values
// Parameters: Input stream
// Returns:    none
// Calls:      None
{
    in.get(item_id, MAX_ID_LEN + 1);         // Read id
    while (in.get() != '\n');              // Clear Enter after id

    in.get(item_name, MAX_NAME_LEN + 1);     // Read name: Last, First
    while (in.get() != '\n');              // Clear Enter after name

    in >> quantity_sold >> regular_price;                   // Read quantity sold value
    while (in.get() != '\n');              // Clear Enter at end of record
} // End of SalesRecord::read()

void SalesRecord::calc_discount_price()       // Calculate commission fields in record
// Parameters: None
// Returns:    None
// Calls:      None
{
    double discount_rate;
    if (quantity_sold < DISCOUNT_BREAK_POINT)
        discount_rate = 0.0;
    else
        discount_rate = DISCOUNT;
        discount_price = regular_price - (discount_rate * regular_price);
        total_price = quantity_sold * discount_price;
} // End of SalesRecord::calc_commission()

void SalesRecord::write(ostream & os) const// Write record to output stream
// Parameters: Output stream, record to be written      
// Returns   : None.                                                        
// Calls     : None.                                                        
{
    os.setf(ios::fixed);   os.setf(ios::showpoint);   os.precision(2);

    os << item_id << "\n" << item_name << "\n"
        << quantity_sold << " " << regular_price << " "
        << discount_price << " " << total_price << endl;
} // End of SalesRecord::write()              

int SalesRecord::operator<(const SalesRecord& right) const                          
{
    if (_stricmp(item_name, right.item_name) < 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
} // End of SalesRecord::operator<

  // Funcions that operate on array (set) of records
SalesRecord_Array read_records(ifstream& in, int &n)      // Allocate space for records & read them
                                                          // Parameters: Input stream, variable for number of records.      
                                                          // Returns   : Pointer to array of records allocated.                                                        
                                                          // Calls     : SalesRecord::read().                                                        
{
    in >> n;                       // Read number of records
    if (n < 1 || in.fail())
        return NULL;               // No records to read return

    while (in.get() != '\n');     // Clear enter after number of records in file
    SalesRecord_Array records;    // Pointer for array of records

    records = new SalesRecord[n]; // allocate space for records 
    if (records == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\aCan not allocate memory!";
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; in.good() && !in.eof() && i < n; i++)
    {
        records[i].read(in);             // Read each record
    }

    return records;  // Return pointer to array 
} // End of read_records()

void calc_discounts(SalesRecord_Array records, int n) // Calculate commission rate and commission
// Parameters: Array of records, number of records.      
// Returns   : None.                                                        
// Calls     : SalesRecord::calc_commission().                                                        
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        records[i].calc_discount_price();    // Process each record
    }
} // End of calc_records()

void write_records(SalesRecord_Array records, int n)   // Save records to file
// Parameters: Array of records, number of records.      
// Returns   : None.                                                        
// Calls     : SalesRecord::write().                                                        
{
    char      outfilename[MAX_FILE_NAME + 1];   // Name of file for output records
    ofstream  out;                              // Output file stream

    cout << "\n\nI need the output file name." << endl;
    open_output(out, outfilename);              // Get file name & open file

    if (out.good())
    {
        out << n << endl;          // Write number of records to file
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            records[i].write(out);  // Write each record to file
        }
        out.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\a\nUnable to save data!" << endl;
    }
} // End of write_records()
```

Input file (order.txt)

```
5
0-8053-7442-6
Problem Solving with C++
1  45.50
7751158146
Looney Tunes Diskettes
12  8.50
88869809780
HP Laser Printer Paper
3   10.99
2429412454
No. 2 Pencil
24  0.10
4895469286
Note Pad
5  0.89
```

Comment: does the file exist in the same directory as the .cpp file?

Comment: It is. Even if it weren't the program would generate an error. I even tested this by typing in an incorrect file name.  If I put in an incorrect file name the program tells me the file name is invalid.  Once i put in the correct file name the program just sits there as mentioned above.

Comment: sprinkle debugging output messages in the all the places where the program reading input to echo back what the program reads. That will help you track down the problem.

Comment: Have you tried "print statement debugging"? Put in little `cout << "Past read_record" << endl;`'s or something similar so you can track how far your code gets before it hangs, which would make debugging much easier.

Comment: @ChildishJack I used your suggestion and noticed that the program stops at the "records = read_records(in, num_records);" call in the main program.  I double checked the function and everything looks right.  Still no errors are being thrown.  I'm completely lost.